# Query data that match string by two columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assume that I have products table with two columns `category` and `name`. 
Now user can find `product` by `category` or `name` or both of `category` and `name`

For example, a `product` has `category` computer and `name` Dell. User enter in search box "Computer", "Dell" or "Dell computer" or "computer Dell", both can return that `product`

Any idea about `Activerecord` query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `mysql`, you can use `CONCAT` to join `category` and `name`, then, make a `LIKE` query as normal

```
Product.where("LOWER(CONCAT(name, ' ', category)) LIKE :query OR LOWER(CONCAT(category, ' ', name)) LIKE :query", query: "%#{params[:query].downcase}%")
```

With this query, both of the cases: `Dell, Computer, Dell Computer or Computer Dell` can be found

Answer (score 0):

Full text search is really what you need for your use case.

You might consider using Elasticsearch which is dead easy to set up with the [Searchkick gem](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick).

Another option for more complex searching, that wouldn't require a seperate search index, would be the [Ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).

But to answer your specific question, I suggest defining a class method in your product model, that converts the search term to an array of strings, and then performs the look up, something like:

```rb
def self.by_name_or_category(search)

  return None unless search.present?

  keywords = search.split(' ').map {|k| "%#{k}%" }

  where('name ilike any ( array[?] )', keywords)
    .or(Product.where('category ilike any ( array[?] )', keywords))

end
```

Comment: I forgot that you need to surround each keyword with %, for ilike to work in the way you need it to.

Comment: Agree that Searchkick and Ransack is powerful and should do the job